# Replicate label with DrawString method

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drawstring

I need to draw a string over a Infragistics toolbar, and I cannot use a label since it's background will not be actually transparent (see in image).

I've managed to overlay the text as desired using DrawString method, but the problem is that the text does not resemble a label. it's thicker, aliased and for some reason black.

What should i change im my code to replicate a label's looks using the DrawString method (same font, size, forecolor) ?

[image]

And the code:

```
FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif");
                Font font = new Font(
                   fontFamily,
                   17,
                   FontStyle.Regular,
                   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);

                drawParams.Graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
                drawParams.Graphics.DrawString("String Drawn with DrawString method", font, solidBrush, textEditorLoc.X, textEditorLoc.Y + 25);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`TextRenderer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.aspx) class:

```
TextRenderer.DrawString(
    drawParams.Graphics,
    "String Drawn with TextRenderer (GDI) method",
    font,
    new Point(textEditorLoc.X, textEditorLoc.Y + 25),
    SystemColors.ControlText);
```

Also leave `TextRenderingHint` as `SystemDefault` and use the same font size as for label.

Comment: I had a similar problem. The `DrawString` method did not resemble, what `PaintCells` would do in a `DataGridView`. The font was thinner. `TextRenderer.DrawString` solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The standard text size of a label is 8,25 points, or approximately 11 pixels. Your size of 17 pixels results in a text size of 13 pt.

Try using this

```
 FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Microsoft Sans Serif");
 Font font = new Font(
                   fontFamily,
                   8.25f,
                   FontStyle.Regular,
                   GraphicsUnit.Point);
 SolidBrush solidBrush = new SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlText);            
 e.Graphics.DrawString("String Drawn with DrawString", font, solidBrush, textEditorLoc.X, textEditorLoc.Y + 25);
```